# Counting number of Populated Columns by Row

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to know if there is a way of counting the number of populated columns per row of a table.

For example if I have the simple table below Called Customer:

```
 **Name**      **Customer**   **DOB**       **Order number**  **Populated Columns**
 ABC Ltd         Jo Blogg      2/1/78          123                3
 Umbrella Co     A Sherman                     232                2
 Nike                          14/5/98                            1
```

What I want is a query which will give me an extra column with a number saying how many columns have a value in them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done via trivial check on NULL (and empty strings for such columns):

```
SELECT 
    [Name]
,   [Customer]
,   [DOB]
,   [Order number]

,   CASE WHEN ISNULL([Name], '') != ''  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+   CASE WHEN ISNULL([Customer], '') != ''  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+   CASE WHEN [DOB] IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+   CASE WHEN [Order number] IS NOT NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS [Populated Columns]
```

---

This will work nicely for a fixed and known number of columns.
Such an approach can be perhaps more universal if columns list fetched from the metadata. As a downside - this requires a dynamic SQL.
Below is an example for **SQL Server 2017** and higher:

```
DECLARE @_SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @_TableName sysname = 'Table1'

SELECT @_SQL = 
'SELECT ' 
+ STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), ', 
')
+ ', '
+ STRING_AGG('
CASE WHEN ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', ' +')
+ ' AS [Populated Columns]
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(MIN(TABLE_SCHEMA)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(MIN(TABLE_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNs 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @_TableName

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @_SQL
```

It will generate and execute a code:

```
SELECT 
[Col1], 
[Col2], 
[Col3], 
CASE WHEN [Col1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [Col2] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [Col3] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Populated Columns]
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

In older versions, such result is achievable but with other string aggregation workarounds, like `XML STUFF` or `SQLCLR` functions...

Comment: Great thanks Alexander. What if I have more than 3 columns (20 columns in my real life table), is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: It can be done then via dynamic SQL, you have to generate it using  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: Thanks again for a quick response, but never heard of this. How would this work?

Comment: @Taz, I have added some example using SQL Server 2017.. in older versions it will be also possible but will require some workarounds to be used, which can make such solution far to be elegant..

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of sharing another approach using `UNPIVOT` to calculate the same, assuming that you will have a primary key/identity in your table.

```
declare @tmp table (id int, [Name]  varchar(100), Customer  varchar(100), dob datetime, orderno int)
insert into @tmp select  1, 'name1','c1',getdate(),123
insert into @tmp select  2,'name2',null,getdate(),123
insert into @tmp select  3,'name3',null,null,null

    SELECT t.*, 
           t1.notpopulated 
    FROM   @tmp t 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 4 - Count(*) AS NotPopulated, 
                        id 
                FROM 
    (SELECT id, 
            u.x, 
            u.y 
    FROM   (SELECT id, 
                Cast([name]AS VARCHAR(100))    [name], 
                Cast(customer AS VARCHAR(100)) AS customer, 
                Cast(dob AS VARCHAR(100))      AS dob1, 
                Cast(orderno AS VARCHAR(100))  orderno 
        FROM   @tmp) AS s 
        UNPIVOT ( [y] 
                FOR [x] IN ([name], 
                            [Customer], 
                            dob1, 
                            [orderno]) ) u) t 
            GROUP  BY id) t1 
        ON t1.id = t.id
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/WDWBI2881)